# neo4j match node in array order by input

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to implement https://neo4j.com/blog/moving-relationships-neo4j/ pointer functionality for using it as a team order machine.See https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt19R.jpg for a model. I am using this cypher query.

```
 MERGE (list:LIST)
 WITH list
 MATCH (u) WHERE ID(u) IN [421, 419, 420]
 MERGE (team:TEAM{name: u.name})
 MERGE (team)-[:PARTOF]->(list)
 WITH collect(team)as elems,list
      FOREACH (n IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(elems)-2) |
 FOREACH (prec IN [elems[n]] |
 FOREACH (next IN [elems[n+1]] |
 MERGE (prec)-[:NEXT]->(next))))
 with list
 MATCH (elem:TEAM) WHERE NOT (elem)<-[:NEXT]-()
 MERGE (list)-[:POINTER]->(elem)
```

Now this works quite nicely, but I have only one problem. This line:

```
MATCH (u) WHERE ID(u) IN [421, 419, 420]
```

returns my original teams ordered by id, but I would like to define my order by the pattern in the [421,419,420] pattern, like a function that

```
return * order by my array input.
```

Keep in mind that it should work for any amount of teams,this is just an example. And that my original team node isn't labeled a team but something else, so we make a duplicate every time. Any input appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If I want to duplicate data everytime i should change  MERGE (team:TEAM{name: u.name}) to  CREATE (team:TEAM{name: u.name})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the statement "unwind":

```
MERGE (list:LIST)
WITH list
UNWIND [421, 419, 420] as uid
MATCH (u) WHERE id(u) = uid
MERGE (team:TEAM{name: u.name})
...
```

[**Update**] Of course, it is possible to know the order manually for each node:

```
MERGE (list:LIST)
WITH list, [3871013, 3871011, 3871012] as ids
MATCH (u) WHERE ID(u) IN ids
WITH list, u, 
     FILTER(x in RANGE(0,size(ids)-1) WHERE ids[x] = id(u)) as orderIndex 
     ORDER BY orderIndex[0] // Sort by node position in the array of identifiers
MERGE (team:TEAM{name: u.name})
...
```